onClick={handleSubmit} not working in Mobile browser
I built a survey form , where it contains a file upload and ratings etc. Here the form works fine in my laptop but , when the form is opened in the mobile browser, the image is getting uploaded (could see the name of the file i chose). Finally when click the Submit button, the button is not working.
const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", selectedImage);
  saveImg = await storeSurvey(formData);

const res = await saveSurvey({
    imgId: saveImg ? saveImg?.data?.data?.Id : null,
    language: languages,
    rating: (ratings ? ratings : -1) + 1,
    month: date.getMonth(),
    year: date.getFullYear(),
    customerId: id,
  });
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let isValid = true;

if (shopOwnership === "yes") {
  if (!selectedImage) {
    isValid = false;
    message.error("Please upload an Image");
  }

  if (ratings === undefined || ratings === null) {
    isValid = false;
    message.error("Please select any Rating");
  }

  if (!languages) {
    isValid = false;
    message.error("Please select any language");
  }
} else {
  if (!languages) {
    isValid = false;
    message.error("Please select any language");
  }

  if (shopOwnership === null || shopOwnership === undefined) {
    isValid = false;
    message.error("Please select whether you own the shop");
  }
}

if (!isValid) {
  console.error("Validation errors");
  return;
}
let saveImg = null;
if (shopOwnership === "yes") {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", selectedImage);
  saveImg = await storeSurvey(formData);
}
try {
  const res = await saveSurvey({
    imgId: saveImg ? saveImg?.data?.data?.Id : null,
    language: languages,
    rating: (ratings ? ratings : -1) + 1,
    month: date.getMonth(),
    year: date.getFullYear(),
    customerId: id,
  });
  setRes(res);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error:", error);
}

};
<input
type="file"
accept="image/jpeg, image/png"
name="billboard-image"
id="billboard-image"
onChange={handleImageChange}
/>

<button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit" 
className="submitSurvey" disabled={!isValid}>
        Submit Survey
      </button>

These work fine in my PC , but it not working in my mobile. I have also tried using React-Dropzone , not working.I expect it to work in my mobile browser too

please indicate which device it fails; android or ios, which version

both the android and ios 17.2

what's the behavior when you click on the file input? Does it open something or nothing happens?

Not seeing a handleSubmit function in your code.

@James added the handleSubmit function

File is getting uploaded ,all that is working fine but the problem is the Submit button which gives no response when it comes to mobile.@BenjaminCaure
